# Can HTML attributes be bypassed?

Tags: html, security

Suppose I have an `<input>` tag with a `pattern` attribute (for example, a `pattern` that matches some format of a phone number), and I don’t go through the standard HTML page in the browser to `post` that data (for example, through postman), would that data still be check against the regex pattern? In other words, can html attributes (like `pattern` or `require`) be bypassed?

More generally, in terms of security, should server side scripts always check against all possible invalid data?

Comment: _"would that data still be check against the regex pattern? In other words, can html attributes (like pattern or require) be bypassed?"_ No and yes

Comment: _"More generally, in terms of security, should server side scripts always check against all possible invalid data?"_ ALWAYS

Comment: I always program server side to validate inputs - client side can be turned off and I just see that as for adding nice functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should always validate security sensitive information server-side. Never trust client input or assume it came from your HTML page.

Consider that with the dev tools that come with most popular browsers, these  attributes could easily be manually removed from the DOM client side. It wouldn't even require spoofing the entire page.

Comment: What are some dev tools that can remove these attributes?

Comment: Right click the input element, then click "inspect element" and you will get another pane that lets you edit the HTML of the page (the local in memory copy), including deleting/editing html attributes.